# Custom validator in Primefaces 3.5 for input text

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My html/jsf code for a text box is :

```
<p:inputText id="trainingNo" value="#{cpeTrainingMB.cpeTrainingObj.trainingNo}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Training Number" binding="#{trainingNoComponent}">
                                <f:validator validatorId="trainingNoValidator"/>
                                <f:attribute name="trainingNoComponent" value="#{trainingNoComponent}"/>
                                </p:inputText>
```

My validator class is :

```
@FacesValidator("trainingNoValidator")
public class TrainingNoValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
     public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }

        UIInput trainingNoComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("trainingNoComponent");

        if (!trainingNoComponent.isValid()) {
            return;
        }

        Integer trainingNumber = (Integer) trainingNoComponent.getValue();
        System.err.println(trainingNumber);

        if (trainingNumber < 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (Integer.valueOf(DirectSqlUtils.
                getSingleValueFromTable("SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(training_no, 0) FROM [dbo].[cpe_training] "
                        + "WHERE training_no = '"+trainingNumber+"'), 0)")
                .toString()) != 0) {
            System.err.println("Hello : "+DirectSqlUtils.
                getSingleValueFromTable("SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL(training_no, 0) FROM [dbo].[cpe_training] "
                        + "WHERE training_no = '"+trainingNumber+"'), 0)")
                .toString());
            trainingNoComponent.setValid(false);
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Training Number invalid.",null));

        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I set the text in UI as 1,2 or 3 ,etc; The object from the event returns always 0(zero) rather that the inserted text. So the validation is not working as it should . I am new to JSF.

Comment: Probably validaton works fine.I think you should debug your big if condition (third one) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [`UIComponent#getSubmittedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html). The `getValue()` assumes that the component has been through validation and conversion.

`getSubmittedValue` is meant to be used prior to the completion of validation

> Return the submittedValue value of this UIInput component. This method should only be used by the decode() and validate() method of this component, or its corresponding Renderer.